# Is it possible to extend the WebJobs SDK?

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Is there a way to extend the Azure WebJobs SDK? If I want something other than a queue, blob or table to trigger my job function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, that's not possible yet. However, you can always write your own event, use JobHost.Call inside it to invoke the function(s) and get all the benefits of WebJobs SDK (logging on dashboard, bindings, etc.)

Comment: Look at the following example. It is a rough prototype right now https://github.com/rustd/WebJobsSDKSamples/tree/master/FileWatcher

Answer (score 1):

As of the 1.1.0 release of the WebJobs SDK you can now write your own binding extensions. See the [azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions) repo for more information. That repo contains several extensions built on the **new extensibility model** that you can use in your applications (e.g. **TimerTrigger**, **FileTrigger**, **SendGrid**, etc.) Those extensions also serve as a demonstration of how to author your own extensions. The [Binding Extensions Overview](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/wiki/Binding-Extensions-Overview) section of the Wiki walks you through the process of creating your own extension, starting from a sample template.